# Aurelia Binding to slidebar

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am having some trouble trying to figure out the correct way to bind a value in my slidebar that slides out.

Event.html:

```
<template>

  <require from="./sidebar/event-builder-sidebar"></require>
  <require from="./event-item"></require>

  <div class="flex-row">
      <aside class="event-builder-settings-panel">
          <!-- need to bind the single clicked task back to this -->
          <event-builder-sidebar containerless data.two-way="?"></event-builder-sidebar>
      </aside>
      <div class="content-panel">
          <div class="eb-actions-row row-flip">
              <div class="action-row-buttons">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="icon-ion-ios-book"></i> Task Library</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="icon-ion-plus"></i> Add Task</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <section class="outer-content outer-content-spacing">
              <div class="inner-content-div inner-content-padding">
                  <ul class="eb event-list">
<!-- Loop happens here -->
                      <li class="event-item eb-item-created" repeat.for="t of tasks">
                        <event-item containerless data.two-way="t"></event-item>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </section>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

You see where event-item is being looped. It generates multiple cards and when a user clicks on those cards they get a slidebar (`event-builder-slidebar`) that slides in from the left and allows the user to edit information in the card. I am currently at a loss for the correct way to do this. I am guessing I would need the event that triggers the slidebar to slide in to pass the current data object back up to the parent `event.html` and into the `event-builder-slidebar`. That is where I am at a loss to figure out how to do.

```
import { bindable, bindingMode } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { CssHelper } from '../../../shared/css-helper';

export class EventItem {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) data;

  static inject() {
    return [CssHelper];
  }

  constructor(cssHelper) {
    this.cssHelper = cssHelper;
    this.toggleEdit = e => { this.edit(e); };
  }

  attached() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.toggleEdit);
  }



  edit(e) {
      // this needs to pass this.data back to event builder sidebar somehow
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `containerless` attribute is likely gumming things up for you. If you stop using that, you can simply use event binding to bind the custom element's `click` event to a function on your parent VM that sets a, e.g. `selectedEvent` property. You can even set it without a VM function directly in the template like this:

```
<template>
  <require from="./sidebar/event-builder-sidebar"></require>
  <require from="./event-item"></require>

  <div class="flex-row">
      <aside class="event-builder-settings-panel">
          <!-- bind the single clicked task back to this -->
          <event-builder-sidebar containerless data.bind="selectedEvent"></event-builder-sidebar>
      </aside>
      <div class="content-panel">
          <div class="eb-actions-row row-flip">
              <div class="action-row-buttons">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="icon-ion-ios-book"></i> Task Library</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="icon-ion-plus"></i> Add Task</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <section class="outer-content outer-content-spacing">
              <div class="inner-content-div inner-content-padding">
                  <ul class="eb event-list">
<!-- Loop happens here -->
                      <li class="event-item eb-item-created" repeat.for="t of tasks">
                        <event-item data.bind="t" click.delegate="selectedEvent = t" ></event-item>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </section>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, if you really want to use `containerless` custom elements, then you'll need to fire the click event as a custom event (and you'll end up having a container element anyways it'll just be a div or something). Here is a gist that shows this in action: https://gist.run/?id=eb9ea1612c97af91104a35b0b5b10430

element vm

```
import {inject, bindable, containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless
@inject(Element)
export class Thing {
  @bindable value;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  fireClick() {
    let e = new CustomEvent('click', { bubbles: true });

    this.element.dispatchEvent(e);
  }
}
```

element template

```
<template>
  <div click.delegate="fireClick()" style="border: solid red 1px; height: 30px; width: 40px; display: inline-block; margin: 10px; text-align: center;">
    ${value}
  </div>
</template>
```